# Split row-details into multiple row in bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am currently writing my first full-stack app. I am using bootstrap `<b-table>` to display content. On `row-click`, I expand the row to display nested data. Is there a way to iterate over the nested data and display it in nested rows within the parent b-table?

Currently, I can display the data, however it displays in a single row.

`component.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div id="report-table" class="report-table">
        <b-container>
            <b-table striped hover sticky-header="100%" 
            :items="reports" 
            :fields="fields"
            responsive="xl"
            @click="clearRowClick"
            @row-clicked="reports=>$set(reports, '_showDetails', !reports._showDetails)"
            >
                <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
                    <template v-for="(proc, index) in row.item.Processes">
                        <b-tr :key=index>
                            <td>{{ proc.Name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ proc.Id }}</td>
                        </b-tr>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </b-table>
        </b-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKXMX.png)

In the attached image, the bottom row has been clicked. The content is displayed within a single row, but I would like it to be separate rows, so later I can further click on them to display even more nested content.

data example:

```javascript
{"_id": <id>, "Hostname": <hostname>, "Address": <address>, "Processes": [{"Name": ApplicationHost, ...}, {"Name": svchost, ...}]
```

If this is not possible, is there some other Bootstrap element that makes more sense to achieve what I want?

Comment: *If this is not possible, is there some other boostrap element that makes more sense to achieve what I want?* => [Collapse](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse).

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer your question: no, a BootstrapVue `<b-table>`'s `row-details` row can't be expanded into more than one row.

The `row-details` row has severe limitations:

- it's only one row
- it's actually only one cell which, through use of `colspan` is expanded to the full width of the row (which means you can't really use the table columns to align the content of the `row-details` row).

But... this is web. In web, because it's virtual, virtually anything is possible. When it's not, you're *doing-it-wrong*™.

What you want is achievable by replacing `rows` entirely when a row is expanded, using a `computed` and concatenating the children to their parent row when the parent is in expanded state. Proof of concept:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    rows: [
      {id: '1', name: 'one', expanded: false, children: [
        {id: '1.1', name: 'one-one'},
        {id: '1.2', name: 'one-two'},
        {id: '1.3', name: 'one-three'}
      ]},
      {id: '2', name: 'two', expanded: false, children: [
        {id: '2.1', name: 'two-one'},
        {id: '2.2', name: 'two-two'},
        {id: '2.3', name: 'two-three'}
      ]}
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    renderedRows() {
      return [].concat([...this.rows.map(row => row.expanded 
        ? [row].concat(row.children)
        : [row]
       )]).flat()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
tr.parent { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in renderedRows" :key="row.id"
        @click="row.children && (row.expanded = !row.expanded)"
        :class="{parent: row.children}">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The example is rather basic (I haven't added BootstrapVue to it, nor have I used its fancy `<b-table>`), but it demonstrates the principle. Apply it to `<b-table>`'s `:items`.

---

One could even take it a step further and make it recursive, by moving the expansion logic into a method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    fields: ['id',  { key: 'expanded', label: ''}, 'name'],
    rows: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'one',
        expanded: false,
        children: [
          { id: '1.1', name: 'one-one' },
          { id: '1.2', name: 'one-two' },
          {
            id: '1.3',
            name: 'one-three',
            expanded: false,
            children: [
              { id: '1.3.1', name: 'one-three-one' },
              { id: '1.3.2', name: 'one-three-two' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'two',
        expanded: false,
        children: [
          { id: '2.1', name: 'two-one' },
          { id: '2.2', name: 'two-two' },
          { id: '2.3', name: 'two-three' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    items() {
      return [].concat(this.rows.map(row => this.unwrapRow(row))).flat()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    unwrapRow(row) {
      return row.children && row.expanded
        ? [row].concat(...row.children.map(child => this.unwrapRow(child)))
        : [row]
    },
    tbodyTrClass(row) {
      return { parent: row.children?.length, child: row.id.includes('.') }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.table td:not(:last-child) { width: 80px; }
.table .bi { cursor: pointer }
tr.child {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items"
           :fields="fields"
           :tbody-tr-class="tbodyTrClass">
    <template #cell(expanded)="{item}">
      <b-icon v-if="item.children"
              :icon="item.expanded ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'"
              @click="item.expanded = !item.expanded" />
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach (that I've personally used in the past) is simply to put a nested `<b-table>` inside your child `row-details` for child data, instead of trying to add them to the outer table.

It's also worth noting that adding child data rows to the outer table could be visually confusing if they don't look distinct enough from their parents.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      reports: [{_id: 'ID#1', Hostname: 'Host1', Address: 'Addr1', Processes: [{Name: 'ApplicationHost', Id: '1'}, {Name: 'svchost', Id: '2'}]},
        {_id: 'ID#2', Hostname: 'Host2', Address: 'Addr2', Processes: [{Name: 'ApplicationHost', Id: '3'}, {Name: 'svchost', Id: '4'}]},],
      fields: ['Hostname', 'Address'],
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<!-- Import Vue and Bootstrap-Vue -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" /><script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <b-table
      bordered
      striped
      hover
      :items="reports" 
      :fields="fields" 
      @row-clicked="reports=>$set(reports, '_showDetails', !reports._showDetails)"
    >
      <!-- <b-table> nested inside 'row-details' slot: -->
      <template #row-details="row">
        <b-table
          bordered
          :items="row.item.Processes"
          :fields="['Name', 'Id']"
        ></b-table>
      </template>
    </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use nested tables you lose the table's most valuable ability: dynamically resizing column size based on content. I mean, that's the very reason why people use tables. You could either use equal-sized columns (but if you want that you have better options than tables) or you could dynamically enforce child table column widths from parent table column widths with a listener on `resize`. But I'd say simply adding classes to rows to differentiate parents from children is a significantly cleaner approach. I've used nested tables. It gets too messy too fast.

Comment: I agree insomuch that if OP is looking for multiple nesting levels, then it may get messy (and squished) fast. I disagree that you lose the dynamic resizing- `bootstrap-vue` tables handle column resizing per table, so I don't see how a nested table diminishes this at all.

Comment: The nested table's columns are not aligned with the parent columns!? You forfeit that from the start.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood you then, you're right about that. I just don't see that as a useful condition if the child row data has different fields than the parent, which is true in this case.

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data. Not for layout. So think of a table showing sales from different periods. And when you click on one, all transactions of that period should be shown (or maybe a smaller period unit, which could also be expanded). You'll obviously want the sums and quantities aligned. If you don't have tabular data you shouldn't even be using a table, but an unordered list. Right?

Comment: My intent was to mimic how confluence expand macros work. Given a pretty printed row of data, click it to expand and inspect it's contents.